# 50 or more file upload not done due to timeout in php

Tags: php, file-upload

```
if(isset($_POST['add_magazine']))
{
    $magazine_images=array();
    $magazine_images=implode(",",$_FILES['images']['name']);

    $path="images/magazines/";
    $mag_img=array();
    $mag_img=explode(",",$magazine_images);
    $img_count=count($mag_img);

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['cover']['tmp_name'],$path . $_FILES['cover']['name']);
    for($i=0;$i<$img_count;$i++)
    {
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['images']['tmp_name'][$i],$path . $mag_img[$i]);
    }
}
```

HTML code:

```
<tr>
    <th valign="top">Magazine Images</th>
    <td>:</td>
    <td><input type="file" name="images[]" value="" multiple></td>
</tr>
```

I have made a php form for uploading more than 40 or 50 files at a time. When I am running this form at local server, it uploads all the files in database but when I am running this form on live server it takes too much time to upload file and it just uploads 19 or 20 files.

Why does this happen, and what is the solution for this? Is this due to server time out?

Comment: wah nipla.. pheli j post par 2 upvote.. :D

Answer (score 4):

You need to change `max_execution_time = 30` to desired value and restart server.

By the way, it's not a good idea to store files in database (as you mentioned in your question). Save them in filesystem and in database store links to uploaded files.

**Note:** Things that may also affect upload process:

1. max_input_time = 60
2. post_max_size = 8M
3. upload_max_filesize = 128M

In a case you don't have access to php.ini you can set it directly from php script using [`ini_set`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php)

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', $desiredValueInSeconds);
```

Comment: Thanks PLB but where should i put this ini_set() i have no idea about this can u tell me?

Comment: @NipamChokshi At the very beginning of your php script.

Comment: i dont get any error but what is happening is when i select 40 or 50 images and that i click on upload button it start uploading for some time and after some time i get the same page again with nothing happen and when i echo the array to see what is happening it shows 19 entries in array list.

Comment: @NipamChokshi I've also mentioned another things that may affect upload process, you can set those variables too. BTW, how much is your time limit?

Comment: ini_set('max_execution_time',1800);
ini_set('max_input_time',1800);

Answer (score 4):

If you do not have control over the server configuration you can upload the files using javascript to prevent the fileupload from timing out. As a bonus you can create a nice progress bar.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are getting the fatal error of something like `Maximum execution time of [amount of] seconds exceeded`

There is a setting within the `php.ini` file `max_execution_time`. This setting is most likely be shorter on the live server (for good reason).

If you cannot amend this value on the live server you may be ale to change the value of this setting at runtime by using the `set_time_limit` option. Increasing the number of seconds this way will just be for the executing script.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Comment: no i dont get any error but what is happening is when i select 40 or 50 images and that i click on upload button it start uploading for some time and after some time i get the same page again with nothing happen and when i echo the array to see what is happening it shows 19 entries in array list.

Answer (score 1):

Theres a setting `max_input_time` (on Apache) for many webservers that defines how long they will wait for post data, regardless of the size. If this time runs out the connection is closed without even touching the php.

So your problem is not necessarily solvable with php only but you will need to change the server settings.

You May Try this:

Add this to an htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
php_value post_max_size 200M
php_value upload_max_filesize 200M
php_value memory_limit 300M
php_value max_execution_time 259200
php_value max_input_time 259200
php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 1200
</IfModule>
```

Read more about those settings at http://www.pacecode.com/blog/2008/09/22/magic-with-htaccess-file-increase-execution-time-session-expiry-time-and-file-upload-size-limit/